# I want the user to pass my login requirement in order to sign in

Tags: java, android-intent, android-studio, authentication

I want the intent I have below to be passed only when the user has passed the login requirements. I tried to put an if statement, in the onClick Listener but it wasn't working out. Basically, once the username and password meets my requirements, I want to pass the intent. If the intent doesn't pass, then I want to pass an else statement saying "That user doesn't exist."

```
10-20 16:53:10.330 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp 

I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-20 16:53:11.510 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 220ms
10-20 16:53:11.640 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1555(94KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 417KB/623KB, paused 0 total 130ms
10-20 16:53:11.850 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Verification of boolean android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(int, android.view.Menu) took 170ms
10-20 16:53:11.850 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 130ms
10-20 16:53:12.780 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 80ms
10-20 16:53:13.660 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30ms
10-20 16:53:13.900 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
10-20 16:53:13.900 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1031(117KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 781KB/1017KB, paused 10ms total 60ms
10-20 16:53:14.340 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
10-20 16:53:14.340 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 282(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 878KB/1017KB, paused 10ms total 80ms
10-20 16:53:14.460 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 297(33KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 885KB/1397KB, paused 0 total 120ms
10-20 16:53:14.630 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20ms
10-20 16:53:14.900 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
10-20 16:53:14.950 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb36d6b8620, tid 2138
10-20 16:53:14.960 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-20 16:53:15.260 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fb36d6ec100, tid 2229
10-20 16:53:15.350 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-20 16:53:15.430 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-20 16:53:15.440 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-20 16:53:15.440 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb36d6b7b00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-20 16:53:15.620 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30ms
10-20 16:53:15.650 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 16:53:20.900 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 40ms
10-20 16:53:20.930 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20ms
10-20 16:53:21.510 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 190ms
10-20 16:53:21.660 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 12:53:24.100 2138-2150/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278(36KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 1242KB/1397KB, paused 0 total 190ms
10-20 12:53:25.100 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 70ms
10-20 12:53:26.510 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30ms
10-20 12:53:27.000 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20ms
10-20 12:53:27.330 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 149 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 12:53:27.770 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-20 12:53:27.770 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb36d2e6900, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-20 12:53:28.120 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-20 12:53:28.220 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-20 12:53:28.220 2138-2229/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fb36d2e69c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-20 12:53:28.270 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView{2c5956e4 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-384,800} during layout: running second layout pass
10-20 12:53:28.460 2138-2145/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20ms
10-20 12:53:29.040 2138-2138/com.squarespace.atpublishing.officialworkoutapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

`

```
      Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button)     
      findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

      mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override


        public void onClick(View view) {

       attemptLogin();


if (mPasswordView.getText().toString().isEmpty() && mEmailSignInButton.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Snackbar.make(view, "You Didn't enter anything", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,       DrawerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });     


 /**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null)

    }
}
```

Comment: What "was not working out"? Re-introduce the original code that was not working out, post it on here, and show us the logcat. We're not here to write the code for you. We're here to correct you, so that you can learn from your own mistakes (and hopefully not need our help anymore). If you hide your mistakes, that's no way to learn.

Comment: I understand. My fault. I just placed my logcat and if else statement under click listener.

Comment: I'm s still having a bit of a few problems, but I'll look into it. I've only been practicing java for 3-4 weeks, so excuse my mistakes. I'll check out that site and continue practicing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your `attemptLogin();` needs to be called within the else { } of your if.

Currently, it's being called before your if, so it will attempt to login even if your email or password fields are empty.

*This was probably just an oversight on your part. If not, you might want to brush on Java by doing the exercises on the following web site. http://codingbat.com/java*